# Streaming output from an API

Tags: java, xml, json, http, jersey

We have rest APIs built using Jersey and JAXB. It works well but I would like to know if we can stream the output instead of constructing the entire json/xml and then sending it out. Since our responses are basically a list of huge items, we want to do something where the caller can start getting data as and when we construct the individual items in the list.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Pagination and client will ask next page every time he needs (end of scrolling for example)